# Detect point of screen size changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect the point when the screen width changes to below 1120, and fire a piece of code, but to only do it when the screen size passes that point. I do not want to run the code when there is a change from, for example, 1000 to 999. Only from 1121 to 1120.

Comment: so onresize, set flag when you detect it is less than that and your code has run.

Comment: The code needs to run every time the point is passed.

Comment: So when you go from less to more you unset the flag.

Comment: Great. This is what I did and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that your code doesn't run every time your browser is resized, but only when it changes above or below 1200px resolution, you can use a boolean(true/false) flag an only run your code when its value needs to change, in this case the under1200 variable.

No libraries are required if you're using this code.

```js
var under1200=false;
    if(window.innerWidth<1200){
     under1200=true;
    }
    window.onresize = function(event) {
     if(under1200 == false && window.innerWidth<=1200){
      console.log("Size under 1200");
      under1200=true;
      
      //YOUR CODE FOR LESS THAN 1200px HERE
     }
     if(under1200 == true && window.innerWidth>1200){
      console.log("Size over 1200");
      under1200=false;
      
      //YOUR CODE FOR +1200px HERE
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .resize() event

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var win = $(this);
    if (win.width() >= 1120) {
       /* ... */ 
    }
});
```

Comment: This runs the code repeatedly when resized at wider window. I needed run once when changing from wide to narrow, and every time that point is passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a modern approach, there's matchMedia:

```
var matched = false;

// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1120px)");
  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
  WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {
  if (mq.matches) {
    // window width is at least 1120px
    matched = false; // Reset match flag
  } else {
    // window width is less than 1120px
    if(!matched) {
      // Do your logic here
    }

    matched = true;
  }

}
```

(see https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/)

Most browsers seem to support it: http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you are looking for?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if (screen.width >= 1119 && screen.width <= 1120) {
        // run code
    }
})
```

Comment: From a quick test, screen.width returns the screen's width itself, I'm assuming the OP meant the window size

Answer (score 0):

Here You have a simple code:

```
var detectSize = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth == 1120 || window.innerWidth == 1121) {
        console.log('youre code here');
    };
}
detectSize();
window.addEventListener('resize', detectSize, false);
```

Comment: Surely this will run when enlarging the window as well.